# PHP script stops when a member function is called, no error thrown

Tags: php

What can cause php script to stop executing without outputting any error? 
It happens to me when I call an inherited function.

Example code:

```
class X extends FPDF {
   function foo() {
       return $this->GetClientWidth();
   }
}
```

FPDF class as in here: (deleted link) wrong version

The object is initiated, **anytime I call GetClientWidth() I get a blank page**

Used to work before reinstalling my OS/dev environment. Running on XAMPP

UPDATE: Sorry for confusing you, I didn't check the link I gave, **it indeed did not have the function discussed. It's there though on my local version.**

Comment: Do you have error reporting on? Try adding `error_reporting(-1);` to the top of your script if not.

Comment: There is no GetClientWidth method in the fpdf

Comment: Yes, I have error_reporting enabled and I get any other kind of errors. At that point though, nothing is reported. The script just stops.

Comment: @Prisoner: sorry, wrong link; the function is there

Comment: In that case, have you checked the methods protection level? e.g. public private?

Comment: Yes, it's public. I wouldn't ask here if it wasn't weird. Must be something in the XAMPP config....

Answer (score 2):

```
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors',1);
```

or check error.log

Answer (score 2):

```
require_once "FPDF.php";
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors',1);

class X extends FPDF {
   function foo() {
       return $this->GetClientWidth();
   }
}

$x = new X;
$ClienWidth = $x->foo();
var_dump($ClienWidth);
```

return:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method X::GetClientWidth()
```

The reason is simple: "There is no GetClientWidth method in the fpdf – [Prisoner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/475125/prisoner)"

Comment: sorry, I provided a wrong link, the function is there, I checked

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code right at the beginning of your script and check if any error is displayed.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

when it happens to me is because the method does not exist.

I've revised your object FPDF an it's not defined